# Consuming Google Data API v2

Tags: google-data-api

I was wondering if it is possible to consume the v2 version of the protocol in something other than C# and Java.  I have tried to look everywhere, but can't determine if there are caveats etc.  The main developers guide at google singles out these two languages.

So is it possible to have a web app written in PHP consume the v2 of the APIs?  Specifically, I need to access the Documents, Contacts and Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/php_client_lib.html

I asked some collegues of me who are using it and so far had no caveats.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I will try it out and post again if I have issues.